# Docker for Mac: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority error

Tags: macos, docker, x509certificate

I am using the latest Docker on Mac (native) and just try to do this:

`docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/all-spark-notebook`

But I got below error:

```
Unable to find image 'jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from jupyter/all-spark-notebook
fdd5d7827f33: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
f08e494cf5cc: Pull complete
6548f4aff175: Downloading
d762b5abb43e: Download complete
c841d1ad6a8e: Download complete
78ff99539390: Download complete
99dfa5547e73: Download complete
408ccccf138d: Download complete
0f7e4eccd74d: Download complete
9177afc586c3: Download complete
b474b13b1b14: Download complete
f204d6cd4f55: Downloading
a8a42c20abb9: Download complete
9ac0b73ff157: Downloading
0553d92e0f21: Downloading
dfaa7db17378: Download complete
262fc767b542: Download complete
a21800239eaa: Download complete
afe6294b97d7: Download complete
3d4589d060ea: Download complete
b81971b6c8e4: Download complete
9daebe0247b8: Downloading
ce63d084a226: Downloading
73eb272114bc: Download complete
b2c0c287ae3a: Download complete
f306272598a0: Downloading
04882c9afb9d: Downloading
docker: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I am doing this inside company VPN so it's behind firewall / proxy. If I get out of VPN to pull image and then get back in VPN to run, it's fine.

However, I do need to fix this problem because I do work inside the company a lot and cannot disconnect VPN at work. I have tried Google and found many Github issues like this https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6474 but none solved the problem. I have tried `docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/all-spark-notebook --insecure-registry https://index.docker.io:8888` and it didn't work either.

Below are some outputs based on what people were checking:

`openssl s_client -connect index.docker.io:443` output this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=GT98568428/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.docker.io
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEpDCCA4ygAwIBAgIDAyF3MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
...
YMYqJP5MkuAKzDL5u0b8mD/EHtoPkfWOIsA5i9YrAAoWRVOJHwfFfgSY+EpXpFc4
AZUPmdZGh6q1YNavRoOL/1D5aP/VBBtofj54uMbKOK8q6vxIXSyzaw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=GT98568428/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.docker.io
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2429 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: F2A7D08F3628FFC3334DBFF7698E05CC5027A61F4F88914E541F466FD6004702
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 1EF9EB10A666597135CA6D5F14F10C717483C4C3873288281D0156410FE93C232E494A0935AA416EA736AE8CBDFBD925
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1462855143
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>

closed
```

And `openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 32 -CApath . -connect index.docker.io:443` output this:

```
verify depth is 32
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /OU=GT98568428/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.docker.io
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=GT98568428/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.docker.io
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEpDCCA4ygAwIBAgIDAyF3MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
...
YMYqJP5MkuAKzDL5u0b8mD/EHtoPkfWOIsA5i9YrAAoWRVOJHwfFfgSY+EpXpFc4
AZUPmdZGh6q1YNavRoOL/1D5aP/VBBtofj54uMbKOK8q6vxIXSyzaw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEJTCCAw2gAwIBAgIDAjp3MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
...
ZI3NjGFVkP46yl0lD/gdo0p0Vk8aVUBwdSWmMy66S6VdU5oNMOGNX2Esr8zvsJmh
gP8L8mJMcCaY
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=GT98568428/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.docker.io
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2429 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 04E8384F625F401B53C8ACA4D1F68A4EC300C0039ABE6C4117DE97C721B58DB2
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: F08AD33B9D234A31DB7A9940A1CA6C4EC1FD780871F117780108E7F39909487B647FEBC5643BF1F2ADC5377407968D8C
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1462857210
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 27 (certificate not trusted)
---
^C
```

**Could someone help me figure out a solution without disconnect from VPN to pull image and get back in to run each time?**

Comment: that's interesting, with native docker for mac, I can't pull images behind corp proxy server at all. How do you set the proxy? any hints?

Comment: Just like any corporation, I have a laptop provided by the company and VPN to connect to (that already has proxy set I believe). So I have no clue nor control of the network. BUT given other things work (like gulp, npm, bower, ...), this should be made simple too, you know!

Comment: ok, we need set `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment to access internet, but doesn't work with native docker. seems your way is different from ours.